# Process Substitution: Process same stdin with two Commands

Tags: fish

I am trying to process the same stdin with two commands. The following command works in zsh but not in fish:

```
echo "\"tom\" is a cat, and \"jerry\" is a mouse." | tee >(cut -d \" -f 2) >(cut -d \" -f 4) >/dev/null
```

I have done a little [research](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608635/206574) and found that I have to use [psub](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/psub.html). However, I am not understanding how the command will look like in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible with process substitution in `FiSH`, but it's also not required.  Piping through to a `begin...end` block allows you to handle two output streams from `tee` separately:

```
echo \"tom\" is a cat, and \
     \"jerry\" is a mouse. |
     begin tee /dev/fd/2 2>|
           cut -d\" -f4
     end | cut -d\" -f2
```

Or, if this is just about matching quoted substrings, then, provided there are no mismatched quotes:

```
echo \"tom\" is a cat, and \
     \"jerry\" is a mouse. |
     string match --groups \
     --all --regex '"([^"]+)"' # or'"(.+?)"'
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you used `/dev/fd/2`.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail, you mean rather than `/dev/stderr` ?  No reason, you can use anything that redirects to the standard error output stream.

Answer (score 0):

The [pee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pee) command solves my problem:

```
echo "\"tom\" is a cat, and \"jerry\" is a mouse." | pee 'cut -d \" -f 2' 'cut -d \" -f 4'
```

If you want output in the same line then use:

```
echo "\"tom\" is a cat, and \"jerry\" is a mouse." | pee 'cut -d \" -f 2' 'cut -d \" -f 4' | paste -d' ' - -
```

Comment: Beware that pipes can buffer a finite amount of data and commands like `cut` also do their own buffering of their output. When multiple commands are writing to the same output stream the order of the information is unpredictable and can even be interleaved. In other words, your solution only works by accident and only for small inputs.